# How to Transform tf::Transform to btTransform

Tags: ros, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
    void broadcastKinectTransform(const tf::Transform& transform, const std::string& kinect_rgb_optical, const std::string& ground, tf::TransformBroadcaster& broadcaster, const tf::TransformListener& listener) {
    std::string link;
    if (listener.getParent(kinect_rgb_optical, ros::Time(0), link) && listener.getParent(link, ros::Time(0), link)) {
            tf::StampedTransform tfTransform;
            listener.lookupTransform (link, kinect_rgb_optical, ros::Time(0), tfTransform);
            broadcaster.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform * tfTransform.asBt().inverse(), ros::Time::now(), ground, link));
    } else {
            broadcaster.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), ground, kinect_rgb_optical));
    }
}
```

In the above function, .asBt() is deprecated, what should I do to finish the transformation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219036/how-to-transform-tf::transform-to-bttransform/) by [johnny.lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22452/johnny.lin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can simply remove the `.asBt()` part. Multiplication of `tf::StampedTransform` by `tf::Transform` will return `tf::Transform`.

EDIT

Both Bullet and tf have almost identical interfaces, but the type names differ. So you have to convert everything using POD-types, for example floats array.

To convert `btTransform` to `tf::Transform` do something like this:

```
btTransform bt_transform;
tf::Transform tf_transform;
float gl_matrix[15];

bt_transform.getOpenGLMatrix(gl_matrix);
tf_transform.setFromOpenGLMatrix(gl_matrix);
```

Or you can do this component-wise by separately extracting quaternion and origin vector from Bullet transform and setting them back to tf transform. But I think the above method is cleaner.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2015-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [johnny.lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22452/johnny.lin/) on 2015-10-13**:
Is there a way to do transformation between btTransform and tf::Transform ?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-10-14**:
What ROS version are you using? Is this `btTransform` from ROS code or are you using Bullet directly?

**Comment by [johnny.lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22452/johnny.lin/) on 2015-10-14**:
I am converting some fuerte code to indigo, so there are plenty of incompatible errors. I am using ROS and bullet together.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-10-14**:
Then conversion via OpenGL-matrix should work fine (the one I mentioned after edit).